# CRT implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm trying to get the Chinese Remainder Theorem algorithm to work, so I've been trawling online looking for help. I'm trying to just get this example of the CRT in haskell to compile, but I'm getting these errors. I've implemented my own `extGCD` function.

```
extGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
extGCD a 0 = (a, 1, 0)
extGCD a b = let (q, r) = divMod a b
             (d, m, n) = extGCD b r
         in (d, n, m - n*q)

crt :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer
crt as ms = let {p = product ms
            ;ls = [extGCD x (div p x) !! 1 |x<- ms]
        }in sum [ div (x*y*p) z | (x,y,z)<- zip3 as ls ms ]
```

Here's the error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[t0]'
            with actual type `(Integer, Integer, Integer)'
    In the return type of a call of `extGCD'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `extGCD x (div p x)'
    In the expression: extGCD x (div p x) !! 1
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't Python.  Lists and tuples are not the same type.  Nor even close.

That's what the error message is telling you.  `(Integer, Integer, Integer)` isn't a list. So you can't apply the `!!` operator to the return from `extGCD`.

The `base` package doesn't include functions for working with triples, so I'd probably change the list comprehension to something like `[ x' | x <- ms, let (_, x', _) = extGCD x (div p x) ]`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! I feel kinda silly haha. Thanks for the quick reply, I'll see if I can get things working now.